# Communication With Siemens S7300 PLC through PC Ethernet Port

Tags: vb.net, plc

I have got a Siemens PLC (S7 315-2 PN/DP PLC), which has got a built in Ethernet port.

I want to establish communication between PLC and my PC through TCP/IP (VB.NET based program).

How can it be done ? is any demo or example program available for this ?

Comment: Google is your friend... [VB.NET TCP Client - Server Socket Communications](http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20020323.asp)

Comment: What application layer protocol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Libnodave](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libnodave)** has examples for many languages and VB.NET is one of them. I have used it a lot my self with Pascal and C.

Comment: I have just bumped into another interesting library called Snap7 (http://snap7.sourceforge.net), which seams to be very professionally made and well documented.

Answer (score 7):

Try also [Snap7](http://snap7.sourceforge.net), 32/64 bit with .NET/mono wrappers ready

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data based on events you could also use the 315's build-in Ethernet cummunication blocks and send a data packet (like emulated XML or JSON) each time something interresting happens. I did it a few times and it works very well.